# Translating the comparision operator in OpenCV to Python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to translate some OpenCV codes written in C++ to Python.
Here's the C++ code I encountered:

```
img2 = img1 >= 128;
```

where both `img2` and `img1` are of type `cv::Mat`.

It seems that in the OpenCV library for Python there is no such function that does the job equivalent to the operator overloading here. How could I possibly translate this?

Comment: You write it in Python as `img2 = img1 >= 128`.

Comment: `img2 = img1 >= 128`is the C++ code that I am supposed to translate into Python. There seems to be no Python counterpart for operator `CV_EXPORTS MatExpr operator >= (const Mat& a, double s)`

Answer (score 1):

`array >= 128` should produce a boolean array that you can then convert to int and multiply by 255 to get what you want. It should be order of magnitudes faster than for loops.

Otherwise there is also

```
mask = (img1 >= 128) # Parenthesis are not needed, I just like them to surround the new object. 
img2[mask] = 255
img2[~mask] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Alas, it seems that only entrywise calculation works properly here. Directly using the operator `>=` produces an array that has some typing issues in Python OpenCV, while in C++ there is no such problem.

```
img2 = numpy.zeros(img1.shape, dtype=numpy.uint8)
  for x in range(img1.shape[0]):
    for y in range(img1.shape[1]):
      if img1[x][y] >= 128:
        img2[x][y] = 255
      else:
        img2[x][y] = 0
```

(By the way, `img1` has been channel-extracted so it is 2-dimensional. If `mg1` composes of multiple channels, go through a third iteration on this extra dimension (i.e. `for z in range(img1.shape[2])`) instead.)

Thread closed!